# can python watchdog be used to monitor directories on different system by runnning it on other system/\

Tags: python, ftp, watchdog

I have to sync FTP server files with another server. Can I run watchdog on server other than FTP server to monitor it? If yes, how? Please explain. I am not pretty clear how to use it to sync two folders. I have tried to use [watchdog documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html) but this didn't worked for me. No event is triggered when I make changes to directory. Please suggest how to proceed.

I could use incron but it could not monitor remote servers.

Comment: what's the os of the monitor server and target server?

Comment: one is ftp server and another is normal server. both runs on ubuntu AWS.

Comment: did you tried to use watchdog's PollingObserver instead of the default Observer?

Comment: Please show your codes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform of your host machine.

watchdog use different tools to monitor file system events in different platforms:

- inotify in  Linux
- kqueue in BSD / MaxOS
- ReadDirectoryChangesW in Windows

Comment: i am working on ubuntu. can i monitor server(1) by running script on remote server(2) . my aim is to sync content of server(1) with server (2)